# How to get theme essentials with custom content

Tags: themes, wordpress, sidebar

I am trying to create a Wordpress plugin that creates an "About the author" page.

I've pretty much finished it except for the part where I need to make it compatible with themes that have a left sidebar and a right sidebar.

In my code to override the author.php page, I just used these functions:

```
<?php
get_header();
//author info and html go here
//...
get_sidebar('left');
get_sidebar('right');
get_footer();
?>
```

I am using the function:

```
add_filter( 'author_template', 'wp_about_author_template' );
```

to replace the theme right now.

Now this covers those themes that generates the sidebars dynamically.

My problem comes with themes that hardcode their sidebars into their files. So when I try testing out the page, I only get the header, footer, right sidebar and my main content.

My queston is: can I get the parts of themes that keep them together and just inject the needed author info into it? How?

Thanks for the help!

John

Comment: Maybe this can help you:
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7168/how-to-add-a-default-item-to-a-custom-taxonomy